# syntax error while executing 2 queries separeted by semicolon

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After upgraded MySQL to MariaDB 10.6.11 on Ubuntu 22, I get syntax error when I run the same query I was using in a PHP project. After some tests, it looks like multiple queries separated by semicolons cannot be executed anymore. I've tried even a simpler query like this

```
$sql = "SET @var1 = 1; SET @var2 = 2;"
```

and I still get

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @var2 = 2' at line 1

The weird thing is that only via PHP I get this error; if I try this in PhpMyAdmin SQL tab, it works. The DELIMITER is the semicolon ";". Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most client interfaces for MySQL and MariaDB don't support multi-query by default. You can only run one SQL statement per call to `query()`.

There's never a need to enable multi-query. There's no advantage to doing so that justifies the complexity.

In the case of the [`SET` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) to assign variables, you can assign multiple variables in a single SQL statement like this:

```
$sql = "SET @var1 = 1, @var2 = 2"
```

Even in other cases where you think you need to run multiple SQL statements in a single call to `query()`, you almost certainly don't need to. Just run them one statement at a time.

Also, the `DELIMITER` command is not a statement you can execute through client interfaces like PDO at all. This is a [mysql command-line builtin command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html). These builtin commands are only recognized by the `mysql` client, not by the MySQL Server SQL parser.

You need to set the `DELIMITER` only if you are running an SQL script through the `mysql` client or a GUI client that supports SQL script input. Since the programming interfaces only support one SQL statement per call to `query()`, there's no need to change the delimiter, because it's unambiguous that semicolons inside the body of a routine are not to terminate the statement.